# twosum leetcode problem, why this solution doesn't work? "Index out of range"

Tags: python, list, range

The problem give an array of integers 'nums' and an integer 'target', return indices of the two numbers such that they add up to target.

Example:

```
Input: nums = [2,7,11,15], target = 9
Output: [0,1]
Explanation: Because nums[0] + nums[1] == 9, we return [0, 1].
```

```
class Solution:
    def twoSum(self, nums: List[int], target: int) -> List[int]:
        y=0
        x=0
        solutions = []
        for x in nums:
            for y in nums:
                if (nums[x] + nums [y]) == target:
                    solutions[0] = x
                    solutions[1] = y
                    print(solutions)
                    break
                y+=1
            x+=1
```

Why this solution doesn't work?
The problem is "Index out of range" in line 8

Comment: `x` and `y` are not indices but actual values inside your array, meaning that they are e.g. 7 and 11, `nums[7]` does not work.

Comment: And `solutions[0] = x` will fail too, because `solutions` has no element at index `0`.

Answer (score 0):

When you do `for x in nums` you actually iterate over values, not indices, so then nums[x] is actually x[2], then x[7] - which is out of range of the list.

Try `for x in range(0, len(nums))` instead, same goes for y.

Or, you can also keep iterating over values and just do  `if (x + y) == target`.

Answer (score 0):

Not pretty but it works:

```
def two_sum(nums, target):
    for idx, val in enumerate(nums):
        if(idx < len(nums)-1 and nums[idx] + nums[idx+1] == target):
            print (idx, idx+1)

two_sum([2,7,11,15],9)
```

Hope it helps and enjoy programming